# Running macports-installed programs from PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, macos, macports, shell-exec

I have installed antiword on my Mac (OS X El Capitan) using Macports:

```
sudo port install antiword
```

I would now like to use it from within a PHP program on a webserver in order to be able to convert Word Document files for use in my web application. So I have tried:

```
$retcode = shell_exec('which antiword');
if ($retcode) {
    $outtext = shell_exec('antiword -x db myfilename');
}
```

This approach works fine on my Linux (Centos 6) server, and also on a Linux Ubuntu client. However, it does not work on the Mac.

I assume that the problem is that Macports has installed antiword for use with my user only, whereas Apache is running under a different user, "_www".

Does anyone know how it's possible to beat Macports and/or Apache into submission so that shell_exec() (or exec(), or system() - they all behave the same) can find antiword and use it?

Comment: What is the output of `which antiword` (both in a terminal and in PHP)? It's possible it's just not on path in your `shell_exec` environment.

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks to Chris, whose comment pointed me in the right direction).

The problem is that antiword has to be in the path used by Apache when it executes shell commands. You can find this in the phpinfo Apache environment section. Mine looked like:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The following link explains how to set the path for Ubuntu: https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable

However, this didn't work for me on OS X El Capitan. I tried both using the envvars file and adding a SetEnv directive into either .htaccess or httpd.conf - neither of these worked.

In the end, I gave up trying to add /opt/local/bin into the path simply copied antiword into /usr/bin, which made everything work. Not ideal, since it won't pick up upgrades, but it was better than nothing.